# How do I increase the width between xaxis ticks in a seaborn facetgrid plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn Facetgrid, stripplot

```
m=sns.FacetGrid(group, col='myGroupCol' , size=15, aspect=0.9, sharex=False, sharey=True)

m.map(sns.stripplot,'myX','myY',hue='myColorBy',data=pandas.groupby(), order=order_list, jitter=0.4, hue_order=\
['T','C','TT','TC','CT','CC'],palette="Set1", split=True, size=15, linewidth=2, edgecolor="gray").set(ylim=(-2,6))

    for ax,title in zip(m.axes.flat, sorted(titles.iterkeys())):
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)
        ax.grid(True)
        ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),loc=2)
```

I have tried to changes the spacing between the sticks using tick params but I don't see any change in width.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well just adjusted the aspect ratio and jitter appropriately and got the desired plot.